# Vertical divider line centered inside RelativeLayout not showing up

Tags: android, android-layout, android-relativelayout

I have a layout that I'm using for landscape mode that has a calendar on the left and a ViewPager on the right.

In the center, I'm trying to display a simple vertical divider line, but it's not showing up.

Note that I have to use a RelativeLayout as my root layout for performance reasons, otherwise I could just use showDividers with a LinearLayout.  (The vertical line does show up when using a LinearLayout and showDividers.)

Here is the code I'm working with:

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <View
        android:id="@+id/center_divider"
        android:layout_width="1dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:background="#f6f6f6" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/calendar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignRight="@id/center_divider" />

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager 
        android:id="@+id/viewPager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@id/center_divider" />   

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this a go

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <View
    android:id="@+id/center_divider"
    android:layout_width="1px"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:background="#f6f6f6" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/calendar"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/center_divider" />

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager 
        android:id="@+id/viewPager"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/center_divider" />   

</RelativeLayout>
```

When you align both sides of a view, then use 0dp as the width.

Another problem is that you want the views to be to the Right or to the Left of the center divider.

Hope this works!!

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation, but it's still not showing up.

Comment: just noticed that you are aligning right of the divider and probably covering it up with the other views. Try toLeftOf and toRightOf.